# On click filter targeting two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery event that fires upon clicking a certain button and then checks to see if the value of a certain containers paragraph is exactly equal to a predefined variable. If true, I'd like it to replace the paragraph with a different variable I defined and also change the text of a completely different element.

At the moment though, my code fires the part to change the other element even if that paragraph doesn't equal the value (in this case x). Is there a way to make this work?

```
var x = 'a string';
var y = 'a different string';
$('#element-container').on('click', '#button1', function (){
    $('#element p').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == x;
    }).replaceWith('<p>' + y + '</p>'); // This works as intended
    $('.tooltip p').text('some new text here'); // This however, fires wiether #element p == x or not
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="element-container">
  <div id="element"><p>Text</p></div>
  <button id="button1">button</button>
  <div class="tooltip"><p>Some text</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: you should check the matched set of elements following filter method

Comment: Added HTML for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = 'a string';
var y = 'a different string';

$('#element-container').on('click', '#button1', function (){
    var elems = $('#element p').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == x;
    });

    if (elems.length) {  // check if any elements matched
        elems.replaceWith( $('<p />', {text: y}) );
        $('.tooltip p').text('some new text here');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$('#element-container, #button1').on('click', function (){
    $('#element p').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == x;
    }).replaceWith('<p>' + y + '</p>'); // This works as intended
    $('.tooltip p').text('some new text here'); // This however, fires wiether #element p == x or not
});
```

Comment: That's not relative to OP's issue and btw looks like not expected behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You are using a separate selector for the line you expect to be in a conditional. You will need to add a conditional to execute that line. Otherwise, it procedurally will run no matter what at this point.

One way I can think of would be to continue the chain and turn it into the conditional you need.

```
var x = 'a string';
var y = 'a different string';
$('#element-container').on('click', '#button1', function (){
    if(
        $('#element p').filter(function() {
            return $(this).html() == x;
        })
        .replaceWith('<p>' + y + '</p>'))
        // The result of size() will give our condition
        .length
    ){
        // Now we run this only if we had results from the filter
        $('.tooltip p').text('some new text here');
    }
});
```

This would be just an example and could probably be cleaned up, but I hope it gives you an idea of how it should go.

Comment: length() should be used instead of size() but the idea is there

Comment: Ah, whoops, I forgot size() is deprecated. Thanks for the catch, edited.